# xsd for declararive UI elements in vaadin

Tags: intellij-idea, vaadin7

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh36I.png)
While developing in Eclipse, I would like to build some declarative UI (without vaadin-designer). But I got warnings and no syntax- or autocompletion support. I tried this with IntelliJ and got the same problem. Is there no xsd for the vaadin widgets listed below `com.vaadin.ui.*`? I found a xsd-Generator for [clara](https://github.com/kumm/claraxsd-maven-plugin). But declarative ui seems pretty useless to me, if there is no standard xsd delivered by vaadin. So there must be a xsd somewhere, right?

Comment: this problem also on intellij idea too